# Observe process in macOS with Swift

Tags: swift, macos

Is there a possibility to get notified, when a specific process running in the system is getting terminated?

Comment: Yes, it's possible with [`DispatchSourceProcess`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsourceprocess?changes=_1)

Answer (score 1):

If your process is an application, the nicest way to do this is with NSRunningApplication. The `isTerminated` property is KVObservable.

As a fairly silly example to demonstrate how it can be used:

```
// Command-line example

import Foundation
import AppKit
import Combine

let applications = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications

guard let mail = applications.first(where: { $0.bundleIdentifier == "com.apple.mail"}) else {
    print("Mail is not running")
    exit(1)
}

let observer = mail.publisher(for: \.isTerminated).sink { value in
    // This will print false, and then true when Mail is terminated
    // It won't discover new launches of Mail, since that's a new RunningApplication
    print(value)


RunLoop.main.run()
```

If this is a more generic process where you know the PID, you can (as vadian notes) use a [DispatchSourceProcess](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsourceprocess#):

```
// 81090 being some random PID to watch for
let source = DispatchSource.makeProcessSource(identifier: 81090, eventMask: .exit)
source.setEventHandler { print("exit") }
source.resume()
```